# Cypher query to implement type inheritance

Tags: neo4j

I have a type hierarchy represented in a Neo4j database. All types have one or more `:parent` relationships which point to other types. The root of the hierarchy has a `:parent` relationship to itself.

All other nodes in the database have one or more `:type` relationships which point to a type node. Here is a simple example where the root of the type hierarchy is `entity`:

#### Schema

- `rat` -[:parent]-> `rodent`
- `rodent` -[:parent]-> `animal`
- `dog` -[:parent]-> `animal`
- `animal`-[:parent]->`entity`
- `pet` -[:parent]-> `entity`
- `entity` -[:parent]-> `entity`

Now say I have a node representing my pet rat Larry. The node has `:type` relationships to both `pet` and `rat`:

- `Larry`-[:type]->`pet`
- `Larry`-[:type]->`rat`

However, under the defined rules of the hierarchy, Larry's types include not only `pet` and `rat`, but also `rodent` and `entity`.

#### Question

I want to generate a query for any type such that it returns all nodes of that type according to the hierarchy. Clearly looking for directly connected nodes does not work-- I tried a few things using `-[:type:parent*]->` relationships to match paths of arbitrary length to the target, but the query times were unacceptably long. What is a performant way to implement the above?

Answer (score 2):

I think model-wise you've got exactly the right idea there.  Performance wise this should be quite good, if you write the query reasonably.

Simple cypher ought to be able to do this:

```
MATCH (larry {name: "Larry"})-[:type:parent*]->(intermediateTypes)-[:parent]->(rootType { label: "ROOT" })
RETURN intermediateTypes;
```

This stops looking at the top, and gets everything in the middle.

Note that this query could be quite complex and could run a long time if you have multiple inheritance within your type tree, or if it's just not a tree at all...in this case in a big graph cypher could spend quite a while chasing its tail around looking for a path to the root, if for example there were edges saying something like `(animal)-[:parent]->(rat)`.  That would be a problem with your data though rather than cypher.  In that case, you might want to instead match a `shortestPath` from `Larry` to the root type.

Comment: Thanks-- this returns all types for a node (except the root), but how do I return all the nodes for a type? The query should also work if I provide the root as the type.

Comment: Just remove the `-[:parent]->(rootType)` part of the query, so that intermediateTypes will include the intermediates and the root.

Comment: OK, that gives all the types for a node, but how do I get the *nodes* given a *type*? I might just not get it, but from what I can tell there is not a simple adaptation of your query that does this. If you post a query that shows clearly where to insert the type name (you used "label" for this, which is fine) so as to get all its nodes, I'll accept the answer.